# Memory Management of Mutable and Immutable Data Structures

Tags: python

What is the difference in the memory management of Mutable and Immutable Data Structures in Python Programming Language?

Comment: In most cases, no difference.

Comment: There are none, other than some CPython optimizations that are entirely implementation details that shouldn't be relied on (e.g. the small integer cache, the interning of certain strings, etc)

Comment: Wait, are e you asking about Scala or Python? Those are two pretty different languages

Comment: Asking about Python Mutable and Immutable data strucutres

Comment: I'm curious, what is an immutable data structure in Python? The only thing I can think of is a tuple. Type hints have immutable types like `Sequence` etc, but those are merely syntactic sugar for IDEs because the interpreter will happily let you mutate a `Sequence` at runtime.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar `tuple`, all the numeric types (`int`, `float`, `complex`, `fractions.Fraction`, `decimal.Decimal`), `str`, `bytes`, `frozenset`.... maybe more

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OP's question is about any potential differences between mutable and immutable data structures. Most of what you listed have no mutable counterpart, and I don't see how those are relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The OP didn't mention anything about "counterparts". He said mutable and immutable data structures, and specifically mentioned their memory management. You said you only knew of `tuple`, but there are many more. And I enumerated them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mutable is a fancy way of saying that the **internal** state of the object is **changed/mutated**.

So, the simplest definition is: An object whose **internal** state can be changed is **mutable**. On the other hand, immutable doesn’t allow any change in the object once it has been created.

You can find out more [here](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/understanding-mutable-and-immutable-in-python/).

There isn't really much difference, just the way the data is compiled. If your on an older machine/OS, it might take longer to compile your data structure or use a different algorithm to save time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with compilation.

Answer (score 2):

The Python Language Specification does not say anything about Memory Management at all, so it obviously also doesn't say anything about Memory Management of Mutable Data Structures nor does it say anything about Memory Management of Immutable Data Structures.

Every Python Implementation is free to manage their memory however they wish. For example, some use Reference Counting, some use a Tracing Garbage Collector, some use both, some don't have their own Memory Manager at all and rely on the underlying host platform.

There is nothing in the Python Language Specification that would force implementors to treat Mutable and Immutable Data Structures the same, there is also nothing in the Python Language Specification that would force implementors to treat Mutable and Immutable Data Structures differently.